# how to get the user accounts and buit in security principles in windows

Tags: winapi, wmi, accounts

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b350914deb.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b350914deb.png)

i want to retrieve the list of user and local service and network service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via WSH.  Here is an example in JavaScript: http://www.winscripter.com/WSH/ADSI/56.aspx

and a sample in C#: http://www.geekzone.co.nz/chakkaradeep/3938

I found several answers on BING by searching [win32  list user accounts](http://www.bing.com/search?q=win32++list+user+accounts&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC)

And finally a sample from Microsoft:  http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/827623f5-eb55-4035-8f57-25c4afb444cd

Answer (score 8):

WMI has a `Win32_UserAccount` class, but enumerating it looks like it produces the same list as `NetEnumUsers`, which only produces (more or less) "Normal" accounts, not the built in security principals like "Local Service" and "Network Service".

You can retrieve everything with `NetLocalGroupEnum` and `NetLocalGroupGetMembers`, but you'd have to do it from something that lets you work with the Win32 API directly, not (at least AFAIK) via WMI. In case that's still useful, here's a bit of sample code that lists groups and members:

```
#define UNICODE 
#include <windows.h>
#include <lmaccess.h>
#include <lmapibuf.h>

#include <iostream>

int main() {

    LOCALGROUP_INFO_0 *l_info;
    DWORD read;
    DWORD total;

    NetLocalGroupEnum(NULL, 
                    0, 
                    (unsigned char **)&l_info,
                    MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,
                    &read,
                    &total,
                    NULL);

    std::wcout << L"Local Groups\n";

    for (int i=0; i<read; i++) {
        std::wcout << l_info[i].lgrpi0_name << std::endl;

        LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO_1 *members;
        DWORD entries, total_entries;

        NetLocalGroupGetMembers(NULL, 
                                l_info[i].lgrpi0_name, 
                                1,
                                reinterpret_cast<BYTE **>(&members),
                                MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,
                                &entries, 
                                &total_entries,
                                NULL);

        for (int mem_num = 0; mem_num<entries; mem_num++)
            std::wcout << L"\t" << members[mem_num].lgrmi1_name << L"\n";
        NetApiBufferFree(members);
    }


    NetApiBufferFree(l_info);

    GROUP_INFO_0 *g_info;

    NetGroupEnum(NULL, 
                0, 
                (unsigned char **)&g_info,
                MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,
                &read,
                &total,
                NULL);

    std::wcout << L"\nGlobal Groups\n";

    for (i=0; i<read; i++)
        std::wcout << g_info[i].grpi0_name << std::endl;

    NetApiBufferFree(g_info);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When a user is not in any group, the API doesn't work.

Comment: The example code was extremely helpful, thank you for that extra effort!